# Maximal beacon push message length

Tags: cloud, comet, push, push-notification, message

There probably is some limit to the length of a message sent via [Beacon Push](http://beaconpush.com/). Unfortunately I couldn't find it on the web. Could you please point me to the appropriate place in the docs or tell me about your experiences? Thanks.